# How to autogenerate DataGrid columns for collection of child type from collection of base type in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

So I have a bunch of classes that are derived from some base class. I have classes (collectors) that have a methods that returns collections of these classes. I also have a `TabControl` where each tab has custom control that contains a `DataGrid`. There is a `ViewModel` for these custom controls. In a ViewModel I have collection of base class elements that are returned by collectors. I want to bind `DataGrid`s to these collections and generate columns automatically, but derived classes have different properties and base class doesn't have any properties that should be shown.

```
internal class ElementsInfoViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ElementScaner _elementScaner;

    public ElementsInfoViewModel(ElementScaner elementScaner)
    {
        _elementScaner = elementScaner;
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<SystemElement> ShownElements => _elementScaner.Elements;
}
```

```
<UserControl x:Class="SysSpy.Desktop.Controls.ElementsInfoTabItemContent"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SysSpy.Desktop.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <toolkit:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ShownElements}">
        </toolkit:DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I removed everything unnecessary from code.


The idea that comes up to my mind is to cast somehow collection of base type to collection of derived type (with IValueConverter possibly), but as collection is updated many times per second, reflection might be bad solution for this

**UPD**

`TabControl` is binded to some collection in main vm

```
 internal class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Test = new ObservableCollection<ElementsInfoViewModel>();

            var certificatesCollector = new CertificatesCollector();
            var certificatesScaner = new ElementScaner(certificatesCollector, "Certificates");
            certificatesScaner.Scan();
            var certifVM = new ElementsInfoViewModel(certificatesScaner);

            Test.Add(certifVM);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ElementsInfoViewModel> Test { get; set; 
}

    }
```

```
<Window x:Class="SysSpy.Desktop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SysSpy.Desktop"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:SysSpy.Desktop.ViewModels"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SysSpy.Desktop.Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <viewModel:MainViewModel x:Key="viewModelSource"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource viewModelSource}"/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid>
            <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Test}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ElementsInfoViewModel">
                        <controls:ElementsInfoTabItemHeader/>
                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:ElementsInfoViewModel">
                        <controls:ElementsInfoTabItemContent/>
                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                
            </TabControl>
            
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you need, but I have another option.
Since DataGrid doesn't have a method to dinamically bind the columns, you can extend it and make it on your own.

For example in this way:

```
class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
{

    public MyDataGrid() : base()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnItemsSourceChanged(System.Collections.IEnumerable oldValue, System.Collections.IEnumerable newValue)
    {
        base.OnItemsSourceChanged(oldValue, newValue);
        if (newValue != null)
        {
            var enumerator = newValue.GetEnumerator();
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Columns.Clear();
                var firstElement = enumerator.Current;
                var actualType = firstElement.GetType();
                foreach (var prop in actualType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(x => x.CanRead))
                {
                    Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn
                    {
                        Header = prop.Name,
                        Binding = new Binding(prop.Name)
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote a simple project for test it and it works in my environment.

First object type (Person)

```
class Person 
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Second object type (Car)

```
class Car 
{

    public string Name { get; set; }


    public int HP { get; set; }
}
```

The element you called SystemElement (Title is used as tab header)

```
class SystemElement
{

    public SystemElement(string title, IList<object> elements)
    {
        Title = title;
        Elements = new ReadOnlyCollection<object>(elements);
    }


    public string Title { get; set; }


    public ReadOnlyCollection<object> Elements { get; }


}
```

ElementScanner that extracts the elements to show. In my test the list is set in the constructor:

```
class ElementScanner
{

    public ElementScanner()
    {
        var data = new List<SystemElement>();

        data.Add(new SystemElement("People", new List<object>
        {
            new Person { Name = "John", Surname = "Doe", Age = 22},
            new Person { Name = "Lenny", Surname = "Pegasus", Age = 30},
            new Person { Name = "Duffy", Surname = "Duck", Age = 22}
        }));

        data.Add(new SystemElement("Cars", new List<object>
        {
            new Car { Name = "Mercedes", HP = 700 },
            new Car { Name = "Red Bull", HP = 650 },
            new Car { Name = "Ferrari", HP = 600 }
        }));

        Elements = new ReadOnlyCollection<SystemElement>(data);
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<SystemElement> Elements { get; }
}
```

Now we have the ViewModel. In my example I did't use the INotifyPropertyChanged since properties will never change (it's a test project).

```
class ElementsInfoViewModel
{

    public ElementsInfoViewModel()
    {
        var elementScanner = new ElementScanner();
        Elements = elementScanner.Elements;
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<SystemElement> Elements { get; }
}
```

Now move to the view side. First of all we have the UserControl that rappresents the content of each tab. So it will show a DataGrid of type MyDataGrid:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Stack.ElementInfoView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stack"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <local:MyDataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" >
        </local:MyDataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Finally we have the main view that will merge all togather:

```
<Window x:Class="Stack.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Stack"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ElementsInfoViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}" />
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="local:ElementsInfoViewModel">
                    <local:ElementInfoView></local:ElementInfoView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is what we have (and I suppose it is what you want):

[image: Main Window]

Comment: Hmm... sounds like good idea. Will get back to you after try. Most of all I like that I can add attributes to some properties that I don't want to show as I wanted

Comment: Indeed! You can manage any customization with data attribute (for example you can use combobox column instead of text)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it works, but have you tried with Generics?
I mean something like this:

```
internal class ElementsInfoViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
               where T : SystemElement
{

    public ElementsInfoViewModel(ElementScaner elementScaner)
    {
        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var el in elementScanner.Elements)
        {
           list.Add(el as T);
        }
        ShownElements = new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(list);
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<T> ShownElements { get; }
}
```

I write it in the browser, so my code can be wrong, but take the idea.
If it could be nice, the best would be to have the generic version of ElementScanner (something like ElementScanner< T > ).

Let us know if it will work

Comment: Firstly I wanted to use generics, but this won't work in my case because I have a collection of ElementsInfoViewModel, so I can't have a `List<ElementsInfoViewModel<>>`